# 2nd time popover is not working after model popup once called

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

In one html page i am using both bootstrap model and bootstrap popover for different purposes. I am using BS Model for Video Play purpose and Popover for Share those video . But i am facing an **issue** with **Popover** and Bootstrap model is working fine. & also popover works fine before Bootstrap Model call after closing the model popover fails to open and in browsers console shows an error... which are ..
**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function(…)** &
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tip' of undefined(…)**
I don't get the solution related, i tried to solve with **jQuery.noconflict(), var $ = jQuery.noconflict()** & also with
**var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict() // return $.fn.button to previously assigned value
$.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton** but same issue coming

if any one face this same issue... and got the solution over same... then help me out to resolve same... Thanks in Advance

Error:

---

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tip' of undefined(…)
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function(…)
```

---

jQuery & bootstrap files in my project.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

/*!
* Bootstrap v3.3.5 (http://getbootstrap.com)
* Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
* Licensed under the MIT license
*/
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

---

Html

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/new_icons/sharing(22x22).png" height="40" width="40" class="share text-center" title="Share"></a>
```

jquery popover

---

```
$(".share").popover({
                html: true,
                title: 'Share this with... <img width="20" height="20" title="close" data-toggle="clickover"  src="/static/img/new_icons/close(32x32).png" onclick="$(&quot;#share_popover&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);" id="close_skigit" class="close-skigit">',
                placement: 'auto bottom',
                trigger: 'manual',
                cache:true,
                content: $("#shareContent").html(),
            }).click(function(e){
                $(this).popover('toggle');
                e.preventDefault()   
            });
```

Comment: Can you create JS Fiddle example for this code ? in order to check what exactly is hapenning.

Comment: Can you write down your hole code that actually demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the popover for the `a` element, not the `img` element (with the `tabindex` and `role` attributes).

Additionally, popovers automatically close on **click** by default. So, there is no need for the **manual** trigger or any **click** event handler, and, as far as I know, there is no **cache** option for the popover.

You can also use the `data-` attributes to accomplish the task without Javascript code. For instance, you can use:

```
<a tabindex="0" role="button" data-toggle="popover" title="Share this with..." data-html="true" data-placement="auto bottom" 
  data-content="function() { return $('#shareContent').html(); }">
  <img src="images/new_icons/sharing(22x22).png" height="40" width="40" class="text-center" title="Share">
</a>
```

Comment: Hi khalid Thanks for Answering the question.... The issue was different and resolved the issue. the actual problem was in popover function there is a trigger manual and on click event of  popover toggles & most important is popover initialize once at the time of page load so after bootstrap model call which is also on same page. after closing a model again i am  try to open a popover it try's to reinitialize same which was once already initialize so next time because of page is not refreshed its was not initialize popover again. simple solution i found that is i remove the manual trigger

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved the actual problem was in popover function there is a trigger manual and on click event of  popover toggles & most important is popover plugin initialize once at the time of page load so after bootstrap model call which is also on same page and after closing a model again i am  try to open a popover so on click of popover its try's to reinitialize again. and throws an error message $(...).popover is not a function. which was once already initialize so next time because of page is not refreshed its was not initialize again. simple solution i found that is i remove the manual trigger

```
$(".share").popover({
                html: true,
                title: 'Share this with... <img width="20" height="20" title="close" data-toggle="clickover"  src="/static/img/new_icons/close(32x32).png" onclick="$(&quot;#share_popover&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);" id="close_skigit" class="close-skigit">',
                placement: 'auto bottom',
                cache:true,
                content: $("#shareContent").html(),
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem when I was dealing with bootstrap popover. Then I got rid of the this  simply by commenting out "jquery.min.js" import script.

There must be a clash between popover and "jquery.min.js". Please try once again by commenting "jquery.min.js"  out.

```
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
```